# How to "freeze" or stop next code lines with readline?

Tags: scala

The title may be unclear, as I cannot formulate exactly what I think I need with a title... Anyways, I am wondering if it is possible to stop next code lines from running until user has inputted something that is asked of them using `scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Question")`?

Comment: Yes, that is what will happen; why don't you try it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I never thought to try because I thought it would just go through, even if a input is not entered.. I will try now!

Edit: Just tried it, and it works! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luis, the question is solved. The solution is really simple: `scala.io.StdIn.readLine` will already do this for you. No extra steps needed!